# How to use powershell to change a datetime field to "Date Only"?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, date-time

I made a sharepoint 2013 list in powershell, it has a date field, but I want the date field to be "Date Only" but I don't know how to do that in powershell code.

Does anyone know?

Thanks

[image]

EDIT:

```
$myFieldName = $myList.Fields.Add(“Date”, “DateTime”, 0)
$myList.Fields[$myFieldName ].Title = “Date”
$myList.Fields[$myFieldName ].Required = $true;
#$myList.Fields[$myFieldName ].Type = "DateOnly";
$myList.Fields[$myFieldName ].Update()
```

Comment: The property you're looking for is called "DisplayFormat" as you can see in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's fairly straight forward I would say.

```
// First get your field using the title from your list
$field = $list.Fields["FieldTitle"] 
// Alternativly you could use $list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("InternalFieldName")

$field.DisplayFormat = "DateOnly"
$field.Update()
```

I hope this helps.